# How does RecursiveAction work?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I downloaded some existing code from internet. I ran it with few modifications. In one scenario, I did not get what I was looking for. Here is the code -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction{

    private long workload = 0;

    public MyRecursiveAction(long workload) {
        this.workload = workload;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        if(this.workload > 16) {
            System.out.println("Splitting workload :: " + this.workload);
            List<MyRecursiveAction> subtasks = new ArrayList<MyRecursiveAction>();
            subtasks.addAll(createSubtasks());
            for(RecursiveAction subtask : subtasks) {
                subtask.fork();
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Doing work myself1 " + this.workload);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Done it ya " + this.workload);
        }

    }

    private List<MyRecursiveAction> createSubtasks() {
        List<MyRecursiveAction> subTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        MyRecursiveAction subtask1 = new MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2);
        MyRecursiveAction subtask2 = new MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2);
        subTasks.add(subtask1);
        subTasks.add(subtask2);
        return subTasks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRecursiveAction myRecursiveAction = new MyRecursiveAction(24);
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
        forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction);
    }

}
```

Check the following excerpt -

```
        System.out.println("Doing work myself1 " + this.workload);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done it ya " + this.workload);
```

I added a sleep of 1 second and then I printed another statement. However if I run the code, I don't see that statement getting printed. I don't understand why. Why will that not get printed ? In fact the result of the execution is -

```
Splitting workload :: 24
Doing work myself1 12
Doing work myself1 12
```

I was expecting the following line as well - "Done it ya"..

Comment: Well, are you going to comment on the below post or accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Make workload static and volatile:

```
private static volatile long workload = 0;
```

Loose the this.workload for just workload.
Alter if statement to:

```
if(workload > 0) {
```

Then you will get to "Done it ya".

Comment: Sorry for the delay in acknowledging your answer. I am looking for why its not working from the code I have written. Once I understand the why, I can get the "how to fix it" from your answer.

Comment: It doesn't work because when you get a new MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2); you also get a new workload variable in that object and it is the new variable that you subsequently test against. This is why making workload static and volatile works.

Comment: ya I get that. But for the forked task (MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2)), compute method will be called. There the new value of workload is less than 16. So the sysout should get printed , rt?

Comment: @user3276247 Debug the program in an IDE. You will see that this.workload never changes. You can add a sleep or something at the end of the main() to make all objects visible.  "this" refers to the original object. The reason I said use - static - is to make it easier to follow. You must be very careful when using "this", it is very easy to get lost.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason as to why the last line was not getting printed.This is because fork works in asynchronous way. So its altogether a different thread which sleeps for some time. In asynchronous programming, there is no need for the main thread to wait for the response to come back unless we via code add some constructs. In this case by the time thread wakes up after 1 second, the main thread is already over.

To force the main thread to wait for execution of other threads, we need to use JOIN.

ForkJoinTask.join(): This method blocks until the result of the computation is done.

So if I add the following block

```
    for(RecursiveAction subtask : subtasks) {
        subtask.join();
    }
```

the main thread waits and we get all the expected lines printed on the console.

Comment: The purpose of Asynchronous is to NOT use join(). You answered your own question and then accepted it. Next time just edit your original question.

Comment: Ok , I unaccepted the answer now. I thought since I asked the question and this answer satisfies what I was looking for, I accepted it as well. I did not know that this is against any of the community standards.

Comment: Also I was looking for why the line was not getting printed. And my answer explains that.  I am not here to debate on the purpose of asynchronous.